# Typescript enum type

Tags: typescript, enum

Есть enum:

```
export enum ReceiptType {
    SELL = "SELL",
    PAYBACK = "PAYBACK"
}
```

Если использовать его как тип аргумента функции, это значит, что можно передать любой его элемент или его самого? (Мне нужно первое)

```
function getReceipt(type: ReceiptType) {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переменная типа ReceiptType может получить одно из значений перечисления, к примеру:

```
const t = ReceiptType.SELL;

getReceipt(t);
```